# A concise way to write functions for arithmetical operations in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I want to sum all elements in `List<Integer>` via reduce.

In Scala I can write

```
val result = list.reduce(_ + _)
```

Is there a way to write this operation in such a concise way in Java8? Or should I write it this way?

```
int result = list.reduce((x,y) -> x + y));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you specifically want to use reduce, this will do:

```
list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);  // will return zero if list is empty
list.stream().reduce(Integer::sum).get(); // will throw an exception if list is empty
```

Since summing is common, there are several ways to do it:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(x->x).sum();      // mapToInt makes an IntStream
list.stream().collect(summingInt(x->x)); // using a collector
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the predefined `sum()` of `IntStream` :

```
int result = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have shown in your question (`(x,y) -> x + y)`) is as concise as it gets for lambdas.

The classes for boxed primitives have static methods which perform some of the arithmetical operations, though not all are available. The ones which are present can be used with a method reference, for example `Integer::sum`.

One more way would be to define a function yourself and pass it into the method:

```
public static final BinaryOperator<Integer> SUM = Integer::sum;
...
list.reduce(SUM)
```

This way is slightly more concise at the use site, however you can decide if the upfront cost of writing out all the functions you will need offsets that or not.